# Complex query using sql in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a question,

I need to create a complex select query and I can't this :

So I have multiples databases call `cluster1,cluster2,cluster3,...,cluster10,`

Every cluster have a table call **games**. And I need to get the some of rows for all clusters in last 7 days.
I tried like this:

```
foreach ($aDataBases as $database) {
   $sFlashParties = sprintf('
       SELECT left(depart, 10) as date, count(*) as nb 
       FROM `%s` 
       WHERE duree>0 and depart 
       BETWEEN current_date()-7 AND current_date() 
       GROUP BY date', $sFlashTableName);
   $r_count = Mysqli::query($sFlashParties, $database);
   $a_row = $r_count->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   error_log(print_r($a_row,true), 3, "/tmp/error.log");
}
```

The result need to be :

```
Day       Nb_total
```

Can you help me please? Thx in advance

Comment: are these databases on the same host? how are you establishing the connections? do you just need the query strings or results with aggregated totals? are you using PDO, Doctrine or what?

Comment: Does't have importance, the problem is how to retrieve data... I use mysql

Comment: the questions are relevant, first of all if the databases are all on the same host you need just one connection and then just issue the same query in a loop and aggregate results, if they are distributed on different hosts you will need to iterate over multiple connections. So yeah it has importance :)

Comment: It's one connection only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a single connection to a host with multiple databases, build and execute the query string like the below.

Note using the backtick operator to indicate the `database.table` location.

EDIT: you are just taking the first result from the each query, fix by doing this:

```
<?php

$databases = array("cluster1","cluster2","cluster3","cluster10");

foreach ($databases as $db) {
    $sFlashtableName = '`' . $db . '`.`games`';
    print sprintf('SELECT left(depart, 10) as date, count(*) as nb 
       FROM %s 
       WHERE duree>0 and depart 
       BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE() 
       GROUP BY date', $sFlashtableName) . PHP_EOL;

    // execute the query in this loop and store the results in an array
    // parse the array later and aggregate your results
    // $totals[] = queryresult;

    $r_count = Mysqli::query($sFlashParties, $database);

    while($a_row = $r_count->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);){
        $rows[] = $row; // this will add every result line from all databases into one single array
        $rows[$$db][] = $row; // not tested!, but this should give you something like similar to this $rows[cluster2] = array($a_row['date'],$a_row['nb']);
    }
}

/*
SELECT left(depart, 10) as date, count(*) as nb
       FROM `cluster1`.`games`
       WHERE duree>0 and depart
       BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()
       GROUP BY date
SELECT left(depart, 10) as date, count(*) as nb
       FROM `cluster2`.`games`
       WHERE duree>0 and depart
       BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()
       GROUP BY date
SELECT left(depart, 10) as date, count(*) as nb
       FROM `cluster3`.`games`
       WHERE duree>0 and depart
       BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()
       GROUP BY date
SELECT left(depart, 10) as date, count(*) as nb
       FROM `cluster10`.`games`
       WHERE duree>0 and depart
       BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()
       GROUP BY date
*/
```

You can choose what to do with the results next.

Comment: Thx for response but I get data only for 07.07.2015 : `Array
(
    [date] => 2015-07-07
    [nb] => 8
)
`

Comment: When I put the query in HeidiSql I get data for all days 07.07.2015 - 14.07.2015

Comment: this is about how you process the query results, with more details and code from you I can try to help.

Comment: edited my answer, you need to properly iterate over the query results

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATE_SUB()` to calculate the date of **"week ago"**:

Take a reference from here

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub